# Live Streaming from DVB card to network

Tags: streaming, live-streaming, dvb, dvb-t

I'm working on an application where I need to stream satellite channels from DVB card to network. Is there any software or server that allows me to stream many TV channels from DVR card by generating many URL to be shared over the network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [dvblast](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjKo9jbgKfLAhXnYpoKHR-WAAQQFggdMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.videolan.org%2Fprojects%2Fdvblast.html&usg=AFQjCNFcoyNWbpcgLijSJ-RnHOwONDO1xA) or use [Mumudvb](http://mumudvb.net) or use dvbstreamer.

I personally use dvblast...it's too stable and very simple configuration ...you can find a tutorial of dvblast in [How to stream all Freeview Channels on to your network](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=10&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjhiKODgafLAhWKPZoKHZ77ABAQFghaMAk&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmattie47.com%2Fhow-to-stream-all-freeview-channels-on-to-your-network%2F&usg=AFQjCNHNBOErrYjXzgBAyDd6cM1ltTX6Mw)

And you must get information about multicast in your local network...dvb streaming software usually send output stream via RTP or UDP format and if your network dont support multicat, you see that your network down after some minut!...if you want send your stream via http protocol please use mumudvb ...and if you intrested on HLS (a streaming technic) read my answer in [Here](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/17816/which-web-server-is-better-for-hls-streaming).

Comment: Thank You,, Mumudvd is the answer for me there is one problem regarding theses solutions that they are not supported !! I think i will go with hardware solution and skip these solutions, thanks again

Comment: What is yor suggest in hardware sulotion? Are you use a spesial brand?

Comment: I have found this device 
http://www.buydvb.net/tbs2911-dvb-iptv-streaming-server-basic-version-without-dvb-tuner-p-103.html#review
But I haven't tried it yet, I might bring one in the near future.

Comment: yes you can use that product but must use a app like mumudvb to send tv over ethernet in your network